# Keep it simple!

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   5. A retired grandmother accommodating man with amazing deal and great price (2,3,3,1,3)
>   10. Fourteen pounds – unlimited amount of weight (3)
>   11. Civil engineer is somehow very sour (8)
>   15. A cross is a straight line (4)
>   16. Poetic form is flowing, meant Peter (10)
>   19. Two times? So mediocre (2-2)
>   20. Comedian Eric Scott ignoring both the far-left and the far-right (4)
>   23. Adventurous lead singer becomes polar bear's prey (6,4)
>   24. Keep it simple essentially making holes (4)
>   26. Preferences for locations (8)
>   29. Revolutionary leader's letter in Russian (3)
>   32. The *Chronicle*'s home article following small company headed by the pope (3,9)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Maybe a lion eats tomato sauces (7)
>   2. Knowledge of nickel on the rise (4)
>   3. In for a good scrap (3)
>   4. Exhausted after losing a wager (3)
>   6. A note added afterwards about Mr. Howard's covers (6)
>   7. Barman who serves Duff and French champagne with no end (3)
>   9. Barbecue interrupted by old alpha ape (7)
>   12. Enemy is surprising Aden residents, perhaps (7)
>   13. Fall back in response to danger after loss of high-ranking leader (7)
>   14. The host of archery events in 1900 is a noted bowman (5)
>   17. Restoring holiest pieces of rock (7)
>   18. Body temperature above zero? Right that way (5)
>   21. Man committed immoral acts recurrently (6)
>   22. Avoidance of endless misconceptions (7)
>   27. Raising maximum after the end of the test (4)
>   28. Involuntary twitch from hearing clock sound (3)
>   30. Beginners excel at reed organ (3)
>   31. Uniform of retired flyer? (3, abbr.)

Comment: The clues are too hard and I can't see the grid (please read my profile). I only solved two of them.

Comment: What riddle is 25?

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn Oops, looks like there's an extraneous number there. I'll fix it in a minute.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat You should distinguish between "I cannot solve the clues" and "the clues are too hard". What is too hard for one person is not necessarily too hard for another, for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Also, it seems like every time anyone posts a puzzle with an image in it you tell us that you can't see it. I'm sorry that you are unable to view images on imgur, just as I'm sorry that some people have severe visual impairments that stop them viewing any images at all, but I don't think either is sufficient reason to oblige puzzle creators to make imageless versions of their puzzles.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Also, it looks like Imgur is banned throughout mainland China.

Comment: 5a was a great clue.  I'd like a 'maybe' or 'perhaps' on 23a, as the solution is an example of a class.   Is there a META?  If so, I can't find it.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Thanks for the feedback! This doesn't have anything more than meets the eye -- when that's the case, I try to give some indication (like "the final answer is..." or similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fully solved crossword

> [image]

Clues
**Across**

> 5. A + GRAN, backwards, containing MAN + DEAL*
>  10. S(TON)E
>  11. Anagram of VERY SOUR
>  15. A X IS, with straight line as the def
>  16. anagram of MEANT PETER
>  19. SO twice, (also solved by Scratch---Cat)
>  20. Comedian Eric is the def and R(IDLE)Y Scott.
>  23. anagram of LEAD SINGER
>  24. Kee**p it s**imple, (also solved by Scratch---Cat)
>  26. Double def
>  29. Double def (Che Guevara and che is a letter in Russian)
>  32. S + AN + FRANCIS + CO

**Down**

> 1. CAT + SUPS
>  2. OF + NI, reversed
>  3. Fo**r a g**ood, with scrap as the def.
>  4. BE(A)T, wager is the def.
>  6. Covers is the def, A + P.S. about RON
>  7. MOE(T)
>  9. G(O)RILL + A
>  12. Anagram of ENEMY IS
>  13. Fall back is the def, RE + T(H)REAT
>  14. 1900 Olympic archery host is PARIS and bowman from mythology.
>  17. Anagram of HOLIEST
>  18. Body is def, T + O + R + SO
>  21. SINNED reversed
>  22. D(ELUSION)S
>  27. MAX + E, reversed
>  28. TIC(K)
>  30. **e**xcel **a**t **r**eed
>  31. U + OF (reversed)

Comment: Solved independently, and came to the exact same answers and wordplay - Except for 20a,  Had the solution and word play technique but missing WHICH Scott we're talking about.